# Decimals of data labels to be customized basis on condition in bar chart in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I created a below bar chart in power bi wherein i have % achieved by category. All the values are in 2 decimal. but what i want is all absolute numbers(100%) should be without decimal and rest all in 2 decimal.

Achieved is the measure i created by calculating details from 4 columns to get the %achieved.

[image]

I want the result like below wherein 100% is without decimal and rest all are in 2 decimal

[image]

Can someone help here please?

Regards,
SK

Comment: Is this possible?

Comment: is this possible?